# How can I remove the default font before loading Google Fonts or receive a ready event?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, fonts

There is a script that handles svg. Its purpose is to change the word and stretch it to the full height of the screen. But there was such a problem that if you reload the page with ctrl + F5, it first stretches the word with the standard font (screenshot 1), and then the styles are loaded and the word is compressed (screenshot 2). I need the standard font not to be installed on the page before the Google fonts are loaded or the fonts are ready.

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]

HTML:

```
<svg viewBox="-2.5 0.5 16 75">
      <g transform="rotate(90 0 0)">
          <text id="text0"></text>
      </g>
</svg>
```

JS(min):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //.....................
    let text = document.getElementById("text0");
    text.innerHTML= "<tspan fill='#282828'>OCTOPU</tspan><tspan fill='#191919'>S</tspan>";
    document.querySelector("#string0").querySelector("svg").setAttributeNS(null, "viewBox", `-2.5 0.2 16 ${text.getComputedTextLength()}`);
    //.....................
});
```

JS(extended):

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    let sneakers;
    $.getJSON( "items.json", (data) => {
        sneakers = data.sneakers;
    }).done(()=>{ 
        for(let i = 0; i<sneakers.length; i++) {
            $('.imgGallery').slick('slickAdd', '<div class="item"><img src="/images/header/sneakers/big/'+i+'.png" alt="'+sneakers[i]+'"></div>');
            $('.slider-nav').slick('slickAdd', '<div class="item"><img src="/images/header/sneakers/min/'+i+'.png" alt="'+sneakers[i]+'"><div class="sub">'+sneakers[i]+'</div></div>');
            $('.strings').slick('slickAdd', '<div id="string'+i+'" class="item"><svg viewBox="-2.5 0.5 16 75"><g transform="rotate(90 0 0)"><text id="text'+i+'"></text></g></svg></div>');
            
            let string   = $('.item[data-slick-index="'+i+'"] .sub').text();
            let firstStr = string.toUpperCase().substr(0,string.length-1);
            let lastStr  = string.toUpperCase().substr(string.length-1, string.length);
            
            let text = document.querySelector("#text"+i);
            text.innerHTML= "<tspan fill='#282828'>"+firstStr+"</tspan><tspan fill='#191919'>"+lastStr+"</tspan>";
            document.querySelector("#string"+i).querySelector("svg").setAttributeNS(null, "viewBox", `-2.5 0.2 16 ${text.getComputedTextLength()}`);  

            countSlides=i;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

cool and smart function you are building :)

Try to put your code in some custom function and just call it in `DOMContentLoaded` event, that I think should do it.

I've also tried to use this peace of code:

```
document.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (document.readyState === 'complete') nameofYourFunction();
};
```

but be aware that this may fire multiple times (if you have multiple widths of custom font I think) see also if this helps

Comment: Yes, it's such cool and strange function:)
I tried using document.onreadystatechange, $(window).on('load',...), document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",...), but it still first sets the standard font, resizes and only then sets my font

Comment: I added an extended version of the function

Comment: can you try to add `<svg viewBox="-2.5 0.5 16 75" style="display:none">` and then in `.done()` function just call `$('svg').show()` just to test if that solves it?

Comment: Ok, i'll try.
BTW, I noticed that the site downloads fonts, but even so, when creating an inscription, it first accepts a standard font and only then a customized one.

Comment: if I add "display:none" or use the hide() method, svg becomes very small and after the show() method it is not visible

Comment: maybe I can somehow load a font for svg and then perform the function? Since after a normal page refresh, everything works well, but if the user visits for the first time, it will be broken for him.

Answer (score 0):

I moved the main body of the code into the global space, and I did the alignment of all svgs inside the $(window).on('load',...)

```
let sneakers;
$.getJSON( "items.json", (data) => {
    sneakers = data.sneakers;
}).done(()=>{ 
    for(let i = 0; i<sneakers.length; i++) {
        $('.imgGallery').slick('slickAdd', '<div class="item"><img src="/images/header/sneakers/big/'+i+'.png" alt="'+sneakers[i]+'"></div>');
        $('.slider-nav').slick('slickAdd', '<div class="item"><img src="/images/header/sneakers/min/'+i+'.png" alt="'+sneakers[i]+'"><div class="sub">'+sneakers[i]+'</div></div>');
        $('.strings').slick('slickAdd', '<div id="string'+i+'" class="item" ><svg viewBox="-2.5 0.5 16 75"><g transform="rotate(90 0 0)"><text id="text'+i+'"></text></g></svg></div>');
        
        let string   = $('.item[data-slick-index="'+i+'"] .sub').text();
        let firstStr = string.toUpperCase().substr(0,string.length-1);
        let lastStr  = string.toUpperCase().substr(string.length-1, string.length);
        
        let text = document.querySelector("#text"+i);
        text.innerHTML= "<tspan fill='#282828'>"+firstStr+"</tspan><tspan fill='#191919'>"+lastStr+"</tspan>";

        countSlides=i;
    }
});

$(window).on('load',() => {
    for(let i = 0; i<sneakers.length; i++) {
            
        let text = document.querySelector("#text"+i);
        document.querySelector("#string"+i).querySelector("svg").setAttributeNS(null, "viewBox", `-2.5 0.2 16 ${text.getComputedTextLength()}`);  

    }
});
```